# Unable to use jQuery UI draggable for iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

I've an iframe(which is a bot icon) in a main site. I am unable to make the iframe element draggable using jqueryui `draggable()` function.

The code snippet is below

```js
$("#testIframe").draggable();
```

```css
#testIframe {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
Parent text....
  <div class="child">    
    <iframe id="testIframe" width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/09hdej6t/2/embedded/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **My Problem:**  If you try to drag  `testIframe`, you can't drag it. Why?

Comment: actualy your iframe is draggable in this example? does it work here but not on your page or whats the problem?

Comment: Not working in the fiddle. It's similar to what I am facing in my page.

Comment: if you drag the graya border it is possible, thats why im asking!

Comment: ok its not working in chrome, but working in firefox and even in shitty internet explorer! it looks like chromes adblocker is blocking the drag event!

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp but it should be draggable from anywhere inside the div with that id

Comment: that will not be possible because an iframe is not really on your site and because of that scripts cannot work for content inside the iframe.. so it will only be possible to drag whats really on your page and thats in your example the "border" of the iframe

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what should happen after dragging it? is there no possiblity to make that without an iframe?

Comment: No. I need it with iframe. Isn't the iframe tag present on the main site(parent page)?

Comment: yes it is, the grey border you see is becauase of your css: background: #ccc AND the padding of 10px makes it look like a border.. this is where you can drag it (at least in firefox and IE).. so you will need to find a solution how it is draggable in chrome (without having people to deinstall adblock or whatever is causing the problem=)

Comment: I got your issue and I updated your question to clarification.

Comment: Well, when we need the OP to enhance the question, you have to rather look for an appropriate close reason. Edit means that you or me could fix the question. But I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#testIframe").draggable();
```

```css
#testIframe {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#testIframe iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
Parent text....
  <div class="child">    
  
  <div id="testIframe"  class="ui-widget-content">
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/09hdej6t/2/embedded/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

It is working now . `iframe` should be wrapped by a `div` and apply `draggable()` function for that.

Comment: No. It's only draggble whendragging using padding area. But it should be draggable from anywhere inside the div with that id

Comment: check my code snippet.I have updated it..now it is working when user clicks anywhere of the iframe but with this update tabs inside iframe are not clickable anymore.

Comment: That's what I not needed.

Comment: @Raviteja I think this answer works properly, but as you mentioned it's not what you need. I didn't understand your issue. What do you need from draggable iframe?

Comment: @AliSoltani No.You understood wrong. I want it should be draggable from anywhere inside the div with that id. Not only padding area.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want it to be `draggable` just from the padding area so `iframe` won't be affected, Try this out:

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
Parent text....
  <div class="child">
  <div id="draggable"  class="ui-widget-content">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100" src="//jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/09hdej6t/2/embedded/" frameborder="0">       </iframe>
    
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope I understand you.

Comment: No.You understood wrong. I want it should be draggable from anywhere inside the div with that id. Not only padding area.

Comment: @Raviteja Which div `class="parent"`, `class="child"` or `id="draggable"`.

Comment: @Raviteja In this case the `iframe` will be disabled so users can't click on anything inside of it. Is this what you want? or you want it to be draggable but the links not?

Comment: I want the whole iframe to be draggable

Comment: @Raviteja You can't make the `iframe` draggable and the links clickable at the same time because the `iframe` data is from another domain. take a look at [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

tried a method for you, as you said that you need to drag the id from the div, check it out if this is what you were intended to work with.

```js
$("#testIframe").draggable();
var leftClick=false;
$("#child").mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 1) leftClick = true;
});
$("#child").mousemove(function (event){
    if(leftClick){
        $("#draggable").css('left',event.pageX);
        $("#draggable").css('top',event.pageY);
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 1) leftClick = false;
});
```

```css
#testIframe {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#testIframe iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
Parent text....
  <div class="child" id="child">    
  
  <div id="testIframe"  class="ui-widget-content">
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/09hdej6t/2/embedded/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicks inside  iframe are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easily possible to Drag the iFrame element based on a Click event that occurs inside the iFrame element itself.

The `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `click` will be targeting the DOM of the iFrame Source and will not naturally bubble up to your Draggable event. This is why you can target elements around the iFrame, like the DIV but you cannot target the content of the iFrame and get it to drag.

In this case, I guess the "why" is important. If you were able to accomplish this the way you described, it would mean that interactions with the iFrame would be superseded, in essence defeating the whole purpose of the iFrame. If that's the case, why not use `.load()` to draw all the elements into the DIV from a Source instead of using an iFrame?